# How to solve 'ImportError: cannot import' when debugging in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to debug [howdoi](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi) to analyse its code. I pulled the code, set up a virtual environment (Python 3.6.9) and ran `python install --editable .`. All tests pass successfully both in Visual Studio Code and in the external terminal. I can run `howdoi` in the integrated terminal of VS Code successfully as well.

### Visual Studio Code

My main goal is to do debug in VS Code. I use standard installation (version 1.55.2) on Linux 18.04. I use standard settings for Python debugging as described in [Debugging configurations for Python apps in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).
When I start (F5) the debugging of the file [howdoi.py](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi/blob/master/howdoi/howdoi.py) then at the line `from howdoi import __version__` VSC displays the message:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name '__version__'
  File "/home/chris/projects/howdoi/howdoi/howdoi.py", line 44, in <module>
    from howdoi import __version__
  File "/home/chris/projects/howdoi/howdoi/howdoi.py", line 44, in <module>
    from howdoi import __version__
```

Trying to solve the issue I set up an environment variable `PYTHONPATH = "/home/chris/projects/howdoi/howdoi"`. I did not help.

### Terminal

I tried to debug running the debugger directly from the console as well:

```
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 ./howdoi/howdoi.py
```

I got basically the same error message:

```
  File "./howdoi/howdoi.py", line 44, in <module>
    from howdoi import __version__
  File "./howdoi/howdoi.py", line 44, in <module>
    from howdoi import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__'
```

### Question

What do I need to do to be able to debug `howdoi` in VS Code?

Comment: Did you try `pdb.set_trace()` as part of the pdb-module?

Comment: I tried. It helps in the way that it stops the code execution. I still cannot successfully get pass the line `from howdoi import __version__`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the wrong debugging configuration in VS Code. Initially I used the default configuration for debugging the currently active Python *file*. It was the wrong approach. The default configuration for debugging a Python *module* worked correctly. It is in the file `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "howdoi"
        }
    ]
}
```